# Is the subextension of a purely transcendental extension purely transcendental over the base field?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, transcendence-degree

Let $K/E/F$ be extension of fields, where $K/F$ is [purely transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension#purely_transcendental).

It is generally not true that $K/E$ is purely transcendental. For example, take $F(x)/F(x^2)/F$. I wonder what is the situation for $E/F$. Specifically, is $E/F$ purely transcendental?

For now, there is little technique I have learned to prove purely transcendence. Nor do I come up with a counterexample.

---

**EDIT:**  I think the two answers are both fantastic. For more context, if they are necessary (Related: [discussion on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34294/462621)), here is how did I come up with this:

This is a question I encountered in learning infinite Galois theory, when I was trying to prove this as a lemma for an exercise, but failed (of course). I was surprised that while there are claims similar to this about inseparable extensions, nothing is spoken to transcendental extensions, at least not in my textbook.

I followed from these Lecture Notes: [$\spadesuit$](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ft.html), [$\diamondsuit$](https://server.mcm.ac.cn/%7Ezheng/algebra.pdf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a difficult question known as the "Lüroth problem", and the answer depends on the transcendence degree of $K/F$.  In the transcendence degree $1$ case, any subextension must be purely transcendental, and this is known as Lüroth's theorem.  For transcendence degree $2$ or higher, it is possible for a subextension to not be purely transcendental.  In the special case that the base field $F$ is algebraically closed and of characteristic $0$, any subextension must still be purely transcendental in the transcendence degree $2$ case, but there are counterexamples for transcendence degree $3$.  In all cases except the transcendence degree $1$ case, the proofs of these statements are quite hard and use some heavy machinery from algebraic geometry (by thinking of the field $E$ as the function field of a variety over the base field $F$).

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no in general. This type of questions are related to birational geometry.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_variety

Where it links to [a paper by Swan](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01389798), which shows that

> Let $G\simeq\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ acts transitively on $x_1, \cdots, x_p$. Then $\mathbb Q(x_1, \cdots, x_p)^G$ is not purely transcendental over $\mathbb Q$ for $p=47$.

I haven't read this paper, and I don't know whether there is an easier construction.